# Average Array Output using Recursion outputs 0.0

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, average

I'm trying to use recursion to take the output of an Array. I've been able to create the input where the input takes the array data but no matter what I input, the array continuously returns 0.0. I did a test print of the array and it appears the data is going to the array so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageGradeCourtney {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
            
    int classSize;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.println("Please enter the class size: ");
    classSize = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newClassSize[] = new int[classSize];
    
    
    double average = findAverage(newClassSize);
    
    
    for (i=0; i < newClassSize.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade of the user at: " + (i + 1));
        newClassSize[i] = keyboard.nextInt();   
        //System.out.println(average);
    }
    
    System.out.println("The average for the class is: " + average);
    
}
    public static double findAverage(int array[])
    {
        
        if (array.length==0) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return findAverageHelper(array,0,0);            
    }
            
    public static double findAverageHelper(int[] array, int index, int sum)
    {
        if (index==array.length) 
        {
            return (double) sum/array.length;
        }
        return findAverageHelper(array, index+1, sum+=array[index]);
    }
}
```

The output continues to look like this:

```
Please enter the class size: 
2
Please enter the grade of the user at: 1
12
Please enter the grade of the user at: 2
5
The average for the class is: 0.0
```

Comment: `return (double) sum/array.length` is (one of) your issue(s).

Comment: You call `findAverage` and calculate the average **before you even let the user enter the values for the array!**. Move `double average = findAverage(newClassSize);` after you filled your arrays!

Comment: I suspect another issue is that `findAverage(newClassSize)` is called before `newClassSize` is populated with values. You're averaging garbage.